# Detect error (#Value!) in range, skip the affected cell and resume loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

**What I am doing.** By using a macro I can add a row to the sheet. The macro is designed to overwrite values in last row, and by using a loop I remove the value "_DNU". A new row is added at the end of the sheet and (by using a loop) empty cell will be filled with "_DNU".

I use loops to reduce administration of the macro by removing mandatory
`Cell(lastrow + X, X) = value`

See the code how I try to achieve this:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Activities" Then
MsgBox "Wrong sheet, you are in: " & ActiveSheet.Name
Exit Sub

ElseIf wsActivities.Range("A4").Value = "1" Then

lastrow = wsActivities.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row

Cells(lastrow + 1, 2) = MyDate
Cells(lastrow + 1, 4) = DefType
Cells(lastrow + 1, 5) = DefStatusActivities
Cells(lastrow + 1, 6) = DefIssue
Cells(lastrow + 1, 11) = DefImpact
Cells(lastrow + 1, 12) = DefPrio

'**One of the loops in question**
Dim c As Range
         For Each c In Range(BlackRange).Cells
        If c.Value = "_DNU" Then c.Value = ""
    Next c

Range(CopyRowActivities).Copy
wsActivities.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Lastnumber = wsActivities.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
wsActivities.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Lastnumber + 1
Cells(lastrow + 2, 2) = SheetEnd

Dim d As Range

    For Each d In Range(BlackRange).Offset(1, 0).Cells
        If d.Value = "" Then d.Value = "_DNU"
    Next d
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

**The problem.** There are formula's in my sheet (e.g. `=IF(ISBLANK(Y36);"-";(IF(B36="Stop";"-";((Y36-B36)/7)))`), if there is a "_DNU" after this formula, my loop stops on #value! (error 2015).

**What do I want to do.** Use VBA error handling (On Error, IsError, et cetera) in a simple and effective way. The error handling should detect there is an error in the range and should resume the loop by skipping the affected cell.

**What I tried so far**
I have played around with "On Error" and "IsError". On Error teaches me something about errorhandling by using "goto", which is usefull. I do believe a solution with this is possible, but it will take some time to build. IsError is a bit more difficult. I don't know where (and how) to implement this in the loop so that it skips the affected cell and continues the loop.

**Additional question(s)**
Of course it is also a legitimate option to adjust my formula's using IsError. So I am wondering, is it better to adjust the formula's or take the VBA-route?

If there are any questions, please let me know.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: `cell.value like "*_DNU"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `.Value` property returns a Variant. If your cell contains a formula that evaluates to an error then the variant will be a `XlCVError` constant (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211091(v=office.12).aspx).

There are a variety of ways of solving your problem. The three most obvious:

1. If you simply want to skip any cell containing a `Formula`, thereby bypassing the need to check for a formula error, then your loop could be:

   ```
   For Each c In Sheet1.UsedRange
       If Not c.HasFormula Then
           If c.Value2 = "_DNU" Then c.Value = Empty
       End If
   Next
   ```
2. If you want to skip any cell whose formula evaluates to an error (any error), then your code would be like so:

   ```
   For Each c In Sheet1.UsedRange
       If Not IsError(c.Value2) Then
           If c.Value2 = "_DNU" Then c.Value = Empty
       End If
   Next
   ```

   By the way, you could test for your specific error like this:

   ```
   If IsError(c.Value2) Then
       If c.Value2 = CVErr(xlErrValue) Then ...
   End If
   ```
3. You could identify the variant type of your `.Value` and skip any cell which isn't a `String`:

   ```
   For Each c In Sheet1.UsedRange
       If VarType(c.Value2) = vbString Then
           If c.Value2 = "_DNU" Then c.Value = Empty
       End If
   Next
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the solution(s). Which one would you deem the better one? My preference would be to skip cell that are in error, instead of only ones that contain formula's.

And an additonal question. What would be the best practice? Solve this in the formula (IF(Iserror(cell)...or with vba?

Comment: Also, I need to educate myself better what type of Data Type to use. I use Variant because this works most of the time.

Comment: Any option would probably be okay. I think I'd go for #3. As for formula, it all depends on what the sheet is for and who's using it; there's no true right or wrong (in all honesty, I tend to base my decisions on what do I most want to learn about/practise with).

Comment: The `.Value` property is always a Variant (ie you can't choose what the data type is). You could try to convert it explicitly (`CStr`, `Clng`, `Cdate`, etc.) but in your case here it isn't needed. If you're unfamiliar with data types in general, then, yes, that's worth a read as correct useage can speed up your code and make it more efficient - plenty of quick summaries on the web.